# how to add column while creating table using select query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am creating table using following way:

```
CREATE TABLE test AS 
  SELECT    t1.column1, 
            t1.column2, 
            t1.column3, 

            t2.column4 , 
            t2.column6 , 
            t1.column8 
  FROM      table_1 t1
  JOIN table_2 t2 
  ON        t1.column1 = t2.column2 ;
```

after that I am adding column in newly created table using following `alter command`

```
ALTER TABLE test ADD COLUMN New_column1 varchar NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
              ADD COLUMN New_column2    varchar NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
              ;
```

Now I want to merge both query into One.

How I can do that ?

Thank You

Comment: Add the new columns as literals to the Select (maybe you need to cast to get the correct data type). Btw, a `varchar` with a numeric default zero is strange...

Answer (score 1):

Although its difficult to set the `NOT NULL` constraint in a `CREATE TABLE AS` statement, you should still be able to create new columns in the new table in a single SQL statement.

However, you would require a second (Faster) SQL to set the `NOT NULL` for the two new columns.

```
SELECT 
    t1.column1, 
    t1.column2, 
    t1.column3, 
    t2.column4, 
    t2.column6, 
    t1.column8, 
    0 AS New_column1, 
    0 AS New_column2
  INTO test
FROM table_1 t1
JOIN table_2 t2 ON t1.column1 = t2.column2;

ALTER TABLE test ALTER COLUMN New_column1 SET DEFAULT NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE test ALTER COLUMN New_column1 SET DEFAULT NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

There multiple ways available:

1) This will create the table and insert data.

```
Select * into test from (
SELECT  t1.column1, 
        t1.column2, 
        t1.column3, 
        t2.column4 , 
        t2.column6 , 
        t1.column8 
FROM table_1 t1
JOIN table_2 t2 
ON   t1.column1 = t2.column2
)
```

Comment: Using the non-standard `select into` is discouraged. It's better to use the standard `create table as ` as shown in the question. This also doesn't answer the question on how to create a new column. Plus it will fail, because the derived table does not have an alias

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name. I didn't know that SELECT INTO was discouraged. Could you point to any references to that? Would consider that into account hereon if so. Thanks.

Comment: [From the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-selectinto.html): "*The PostgreSQL usage of SELECT INTO to represent table creation is historical. It is best to use CREATE TABLE AS for this purpose in new code*"